# One form to another form HTML

Tags: html, forms

I am working on my school work and I am trying to add subtitles when user upload video to webpage. The source code was created earlier and I only added code at row 12 -18.

```html
<div class="form-group">             
               <input type="checkbox" id="inputCheck" name="enhancement">
                <label for="inputCheck"> Add subtitles(text): </label>
         <form id="post" accept-charset="UTF-8"  name="post" method="post" action="/application/controllers/media.php">
                       <textarea rows="5" cols="85" name="blogentry" form="post"></textarea>
                       <input class="button" type="submit" value="Submit">
         </form>            
        </div>
```

I tried this code alone and it works, so it saved subtitles to file on server. But when I added it to this source code it doesn't work. I know it doesn't work because there is "form in form". Please kindly I need your help. I don't know how to transfer this two forms to just one form. I am new in HTML and I don't know how to do it.

```html
    <form action="<?php echo base_url();?>media/upload" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="form1">
        <div class="form-group">
            <select name="gender" class="form-control hide-scroll" size="<?php echo sizeof($gender_list);?>">
                    <?php foreach($gender_list as $key => $gender):?>
                        <option <?php if($key==0) echo 'selected="selected"';?> value="<?php echo $gender['gender_name'];?>"><?php echo $gender['gender_name'];?></option>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </select>            
        </div>        
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputFile" class="col-sm-2 control-label input-sm m-bot15">Add file:</label>            
        </div>    
       <div class="form-group">             
               <input type="checkbox" id="inputCheck" name="enhancement">
                <label for="inputCheck"> Add subtitles(text): </label>
         <form id="post" accept-charset="UTF-8"  name="post" method="post" action="/application/controllers/media.php">
                       <textarea rows="5" cols="85" name="blogentry" form="post"></textarea>
                       <input class="button" type="submit" value="Submit">
         </form>            
        </div> 
        <div class="form-group">            
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info col-sm-12"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></i> Upload</button>           
        </div>        
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two forms there. You need only one form on client-side and script, which adds subtitles to DB/file if $_POST['inputCheck'] == true - on server-side. You only need to reorganize server-side script.

On client-side you only need to remove internal 'form' tag.

On server-side you need to move script from '/application/controllers/media.php' to 'media/upload'. That's all.